# Google Play Billing library 5 requirement

Tags: java, android, eclipse, play-billing-library

After a week of trying to find a solution, I am quite desperate to find (and I have read everything related to the topic) any way to resolve the issue.

I am trying to use Google Play Billing library 5 (as required by Google) in my Android App. However, I had created my app 8 years ago in Eclipse (in Java, not Android Studio), so please mind I am just trying to keep my app updated (over 30k daily users) and I may have made some beginners mistakes like missing something in `AndroidManifest.xml`. I am able to include the library (version 5.0) in my build and after calling:

```
billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
        if (billingResult.getResponseCode() ==  BillingResponseCode.OK) {
            // The BillingClient is ready. You can query purchases here.
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
        // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
        // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
    }
});
```

The response code is `BillingResponseCode.OK`, then I `queryProductDetailsAsync()` and I am able to get all items from my Google Play Console successfully (I get all the details like prices etc., so it means I am able to connect to Google). However, as soon as I call `billingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, billingFlowParams);` my listener:

```
void onPurchasesUpdated(BillingResult billingResult, List<Purchase> purchases) {
    if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingResponseCode.OK
        && purchases != null) {
        for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {
            handlePurchase(purchase);
        }
    } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {
        // Handle an error caused by a user cancelling the purchase flow.
    } else {
        // Handle any other error codes.
    }
}
```

get a response code `billingResult.getResponseCode()` with value `SERVICE_DISCONNECTED` (-1) with `getDebugMessage()` stating "Service connection is disconnected". Even if I call functions (after the service disconnected message) like `getConnectionState()`, I am getting response `CONNECTED` (2) and also function `isReady()` is returning `true` where Google says it means *"Checks if the client is currently connected to the service, so that requests to other methods will succeed."*

After so many attempts over last week, I am unable to find any solution to this issue (reconnecting etc.). Thank you a lot for any possible solution for my issue.

Comment: Make sure that you have the necessary permissions declared in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. The Billing Library requires the `com.android.vending.BILLING` permission.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, I had to remove `com.android.vending.BILLING` from `AndroidManifest.xml` because if I include it, I am getting an error from Google (after uploading .apk) that my app includes old `AIDL` billing library. Maybe I am missing something but Google states that *"Embedded billing permission inside library’s manifest. It's not necessary to add the com.android.vending.BILLING permission inside Android manifest anymore."*

Comment: Eclipse hasn't been supported for Android development for some years now. It may be you are running in to issues that require Android Studio.